# XSD pattern that accept 5 number which does not begin with specific values

Tags: regex, xsd

I'd like to use regex to see if a number does not begin with a certain values. 
My pattern should accept all numbers between 01000 and 98899 except those who start by  977,978,979,981,982,983,984,985
I tried this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="CodeType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:pattern value="(?!(977|978|979|981|982|983|984|985))\d{5}" />
        <xsd:minInclusive value="1000" />
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="98899" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

but it seems doesn't work int XSD Pattern

Comment: You say max is `98800` but in code, you have `<xsd:maxInclusive value="98899" />`. Looks like that must be `98799`. **Also, lookarounds are not supported.** You can't use `(?!...)` in XSD regex.

Comment: It was just a typing mistake, I have rectified

Comment: Try [`^([0-8]\d{4}|97[0-6]\d{2}|98[06-9]\d{2}|9[0-69]\d{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/gP5gJ0/1).

Comment: @stribizhev it doesn't work

Comment: Even if written as `([0-8][0-9]{4}|97[0-6][0-9]{2}|98[06-9][0-9]{2}|9[0-69][0-9]{3})`?

Comment: @stribizhev it works perfectly , thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that XSD pattern does not support lookarounds. Thus, you have to unwrap the pattern as

```
([0-8][0-9]{4}|97[0-6][0-9]{2}|98[06-9][0-9]{2}|9[0-69][0-9]{3})
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP5gJ0/1)

Since the XSD pattern is anchored by default, we should not use `^` and `$` on both sides and to avoid issues with backslashes, I suggest replacing `\d` with `[0-9]` (it will also make the pattern match normal digits rather than all Unicode ones).

All the alternatives here match 5 digits.

- `[0-8][0-9]{4}` - all integers that start with `00000` up to `89999`
- `97[0-6][0-9]{2}` - integers from `97000` up to `97699`
- `98[06-9][0-9]{2}` - integers from `98000` up to `98999` excluding your unwanted ones (whitelisting approach)
- `9[0-69][0-9]{3}` - integers from `90000` up to `96999` and `99000` to `99999`.

The restrictions you use in the code further restrict the regex.

Comment: Very cool +1.  Did you create this manually?   Minor observation: I think `9[0-69][0-9]{3}` in last alternative can be reduced to `9[0-6][0-9]{3}` since 99xxx's are eliminated by `<xsd:maxInclusive value="98899"/>`.  Also, this is a good candidate for multiple `xsd:pattern` facets written to parallel your nice explanatory bullets.  Nice job!

Comment: @kjhughes: I wrote it manually. I have been working on a numeric range regex creation code in Python and C#, but exclusion is not easy since it uses reverse logic. Yes, that could be reduced for this case, I just was more focused on converting OP regex that matched all 5-digit numbers excluding specific ones. Maybe the order of the alternatives can be adjusted as well.

Answer (score 1):

I really love [stribizhev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687306/3870761), but I want to propose two different ideas.

In XSD 1.1 you can use **xs:assertion** to test that some value does not start with some other value:

```
    <xsd:simpleType name="CodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1000" />
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="98899" />
            <xsd:assertion test="every $notAllowedPrefix in ('977','978','979','981','982','983','984','985') satisfies
                not(starts-with(string($value), $notAllowedPrefix))"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

In every XSD version you can use **xs:union** to allow multiple value ranges in a simpleType:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="CodeType">
    <xsd:union>
        <!-- From 1000 to 97699 -->
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                <xsd:minInclusive value="1000" />
                <xsd:maxInclusive value="97699" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <!-- From 98000 to 98199 -->
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                <xsd:minInclusive value="98000" />
                <xsd:maxInclusive value="98199" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <!-- From 98600 to 98999 -->
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                <xsd:minInclusive value="98600" />
                <xsd:maxInclusive value="98999" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>            
    </xsd:union>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Note that an integer value can be expressed using different literals, e.g.: 1000=01000. My solution works restricting values (it allows 1000, 01000, 00001000, etc), while using pattern restricts literal values. My ideas allows 9700 and 09700 while stribizhev solution only allows 09700 but not 9700. If you were using floats you could also use 1000=01000=1e3=1E3 so restricting values could be more maintanable than restricting literales depending on the case.

In addition, note that you can use multiple **xs:pattern** inside xs:restriction, and the simpleType must match at least one of them to be valid. So you can use stribizhev answer in many ways: the complete regex in a single pattern or split in multiple xs:pattern if you want it or you see it more clear that way.